# Pytest Testing Try Catch Exception print message

Tags: python, exception, printing, try-catch

Need to create a Pytest to test whether a function prints out an error message, rather than raising the exception, following a try/catch exception print block.

Actual function:

def location2index(loc: str) -> tuple[int, int]:
#converts chess location to corresponding x and y coordinates

```
try:
    if (loc[0].isalpha() and loc[1:].isnumeric()):
        a = ord(loc[0]) - 96
        b = int(loc[1:])
        return (a, b)
    else:
        raise ValueError ('The format of the location in the file is not correct')
except ValueError as V:
        print(V)
```

Pytest function:

```
def test_location2index5():  
    with pytest.raises (ValueError): location2index('aa2')
```

Would be very grateful for your advice as always!!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `capsys` fixture to check stdout:

```py
def test_location2index5(capsys):
    location2index('aa2')
    out, err = capsys.readouterr()
    assert "The format of the location in the file is not correct" in out
```